# Sufficient conditions for $\dfrac{1-x^a}{1-x^b} > 1/2$ for all $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

What are the sufficient conditions for the following inequality to be true all $x>0.$

$\dfrac{1-x^a}{1-x^b} > \frac{1}{2},\,$ where $0<a\leq b$ and $b\geq 1$.

Of course, the case is trivial when $a=b.$ And, the limiting case $x \to 1$ must be considered too. Though, I'm only interested in this when $x \neq 1.$

Also, is it possible to state the necessary conditions?.

Comment: Consider $x\to\infty$.

Comment: It *can't* be true for all $x > 0$.  If it were true for all $x > 0$ it would be true for $x = 1$.... and it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting $y = x^b$ and $\alpha = a/b \le 1$, one only needs to consider the function $f_\alpha(y) = \frac{1 - y^\alpha}{1-y}$. Note that this function is non-increasing for $y \ge 0$. Therefore its infimum on $[0,\infty)$ is its limit as $y \to \infty$, which is easily seen to be 0 for $\alpha < 1$ and 1 for $\alpha = 1$.

Therefore the only case with $ a \le b$ where $\frac{1-x^a}{1-x^b} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \ge 0$ is the trivial case, $a = b$.

*For $x = 1$, the limit of the ratio is $\frac{a}{b} =  \alpha$, so there is no problem.*